# Invoke-Sqlcmd for schema & stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I managed to execute schema query using `Invoke-Sqlcmd`, however unsure `Invoke-Sqlcmd` same suitable used for stored procedure too.

Command:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DBName
      -Query $QueryString -QueryTimeout $ConnectionTimeout 
      -Username  $Username -Password $Password -ErrorAction Stop -verbose
```

Will I be able to use `Invoke-Sqlcmd` for executing large chunk of stored procedure code? Is there any good way to verify the result as there is no status/result returned after command execution?

Comment: If the sprocs don't return anything, how would you know if they work as intended?

Comment: An error thrown from the procedure should feed back to Powershell, so a `try` `catch` should work

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned "Invoke-Sqlcmd" can be used to run any query against SQL databases.
If you ask how to run stored procedures using "Invoke-Sqlcmd" this is simply done by running the stored procedure as the query string as follow

```
# if the stored procedure name is "STP_stored_procedure" and accept 2 parameters $param1 and $param2

$QueryString = 'STP_stored_procedure $param1, $param2'

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DBName
  -Query $QueryString -QueryTimeout $ConnectionTimeout 
  -Username  $Username -Password $Password -ErrorAction Stop -verbose
```

if command fails, output will be displayed on screen, no output mean command executed successfully